# Java Vaadin 6 to 7 upgrade

Tags: java, vaadin

Trying to upgrade from 6 to 7 VAADIN getting the following error.
I new to Java and Vaadin any help would be nice. 
Thanks

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method getMainWindow() is undefined for the type

```
private void periodicRefresh() {
    // Logout if requested
    if (mKicker != null) {
        String kickMessage = KickoutMessageText + mKicker.getData().getName();
        mKicker = null;
        logoutCore();
        getMainWindow().showNotification(KickoutMessageTitle, kickMessage, Notification.TYPE_WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }

    // Refresh logged in users
    refreshLoggedInUsers();

    // Refresh GPIO pin states
    refreshGPIOPinStates();

}
```

Second problem:
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method getMainWindow() is undefined for the type new LoginForm.LoginListener()

also in same code
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method addComponent(LoginForm) is undefined for the type Panel

```
    private void createLoginUI(final AbstractOrderedLayout parentLayout) {
    final Rpi_gpio_controllerApplication application = this;

    LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
    loginForm.addListener(new LoginForm.LoginListener() {
        Rpi_gpio_controllerApplication mApplication = application;

        @Override
        public void onLogin(LoginEvent event) {
            String loginErrorMessage = new User(
                    new UserData(event.getLoginParameter("username"), event.getLoginParameter("password")),
                    mApplication).login();
            if (loginErrorMessage != null) {
                Notification notification = new Notification(LoginErrorMessage, loginErrorMessage,
                        Notification.TYPE_ERROR_MESSAGE);
                notification.setDelayMsec(1000);
                getMainWindow().showNotification(notification);
            }
        }
    });

    Panel loginPanel = new Panel("Log in!!!!");
    loginPanel.setWidth("200px");
    loginPanel.setHeight("250px");
    loginPanel.addComponent(loginForm);

    parentLayout.addComponent(loginPanel);
    parentLayout.setComponentAlignment(loginPanel, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st the notification are used in other way:

```
Notification.show(KickoutMessageTitle, kickMessage, Notification.TYPE_WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

2nd - panel in 6 has a default content and You can add components to it,
in version 7 the content must be set by You.

Solution -  create a Layout (contentLayout) and use setContent(contentLayout)
then add other components to the contentLayout

If You need to get a Window (like the getMainWindowMethod) in vaadin 7 You need to use:

```
UI.getCurrent().getWindow()
```

EDIT:

1:

```
private void periodicRefresh() {
// Logout if requested
if (mKicker != null) {
    String kickMessage = KickoutMessageText + mKicker.getData().getName();
    mKicker = null;
    logoutCore();
    Notification.show(KickoutMessageTitle, kickMessage, Notification.TYPE_WARNING_MESSAGE);
}

// Refresh logged in users
refreshLoggedInUsers();

// Refresh GPIO pin states
refreshGPIOPinStates();
```

}

2:

```
private void createLoginUI(final AbstractOrderedLayout parentLayout) {
final Rpi_gpio_controllerApplication application = this;

LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
loginForm.addListener(new LoginForm.LoginListener() {
    Rpi_gpio_controllerApplication mApplication = application;

    @Override
    public void onLogin(LoginEvent event) {
        String loginErrorMessage = new User(
                new UserData(event.getLoginParameter("username"), event.getLoginParameter("password")),
                mApplication).login();
        if (loginErrorMessage != null) {
            Notification notification = new Notification(LoginErrorMessage, loginErrorMessage,
                    Notification.TYPE_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            notification.setDelayMsec(1000);
            notification.show(Page.getCurrent());
        }
    }
});

Panel loginPanel = new Panel("Log in!!!!");
loginPanel.setWidth("200px");
loginPanel.setHeight("250px");
loginPanel.setContent(loginForm);

parentLayout.addComponent(loginPanel);
parentLayout.setComponentAlignment(loginPanel, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
```

}

Comment: so does it need to be like:     <br/>                                 UI.getCurrent().getWindows();
Notification.show(KickoutMessageTitle,  kickMessage, Notification.Type.WARNING_MESSAGE);